# How to list the sub directories in a Windows FTP server?

Tags: windows, unix, ftp, command

I'm trying to list all the directories and sub directories in a windows server from Unix FTP command. I tried `dir -r` command but it only displays the directories in current folder. `dir /s` command is not displaying anything. I don't have utilities like winexe also. Any idea would greatly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no command to list directories recursively in the common *nix `ftp` command-line *client*.

Some FTP *servers* (like ProFTPD) support switches to the `LIST` command (and similar). But that's a non-standard behavior that does not have any backing in the FTP specification/RFC.

You didn't specify what Windows FTP server you are using. Assuming IIS: The IIS does not support any switches at all, what is the correct behavior. It is a task for the client to do the recursion. But again, the common *nix `ftp` client does not support that.

---

Similar question:
[Get a whole FTP directory listings recursively in one call possible to reduce time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72793174/850848)

Answer (score -1):

Try `dir -R`. `dir /s` is a windows command, and `dir -r` is reversing the output order.

Comment: Hi. I tried dir -R .. Still it is displaying the directories in current folder only. :(