# Get a whole FTP directory listings recursively in one call possible to reduce time

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

Get a whole FTP directory listings recursively in one call if possible to reduce time using possibly Apache Commons API. Right now I have to call it multiple times to get all the directory listings is there any solutions for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to request recursive directory listing from remote server in "one call".

So even if the Apache Common Net (or any other library) had a single call API to request recursive directory listing, it would internally have to do the same recursive algorithm, as for example here:
[Retrieve all sub folders contents using Java Apache Commons Net library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55096136/850848)

---

Some FTP servers support a non-standard request for recursive listing.

For example [ProFTPD has `-R` switch](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ListOptions.html) to `LIST` command (and similar) to list the directories recursively.

In Apache Commons Net you can inject that switch by simply prepending it to the path:

```
ftpClient.listFiles("-R " + remotePath);
```

But you can use that only if you know for sure that you are connected to ProFTPD.

---

I do not know of any other FTP server with similar functionality. With other FTP servers you can optimize the listing by using multiple parallel connections.

If you have a choice of protocols, consider using WebDAV, as that's the only file transfer protocol I know of that supports recursive directory listing.

---

Similar question:
[How to list the sub directories in a Windows FTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42050334/850848)